# jQuery only work for first checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

why this script:

```
$("#generujbox").change(function ()
{
   var idcheck = $(this).val();

   if ($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
      $("p").text(idcheck);
   }
   else
   {
      $("p").text("unchecked");
   }
});
```

Only working for first checkbox on website ?
I have many checkbox with id = generujbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique!!!

the id selector will return only the first element with the said id, so the click handler will get added only to the first element

You can use class for similar elements

```
<input class="generujbox" type="checkbox" />
```

then

```
$(".generujbox").change(function () {
    var idcheck = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("p").text(idcheck);
    } else {
        $("p").text("unchecked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an ID. If you select an ID it will only select the first one (because it is assumed they are unique). You should be using classes instead and you can select like `.generujbox`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r43yX/)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="generujbox" value="a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="generujbox" value="b" />
<input type="checkbox" class="generujbox" value="c" />
<input type="checkbox" class="generujbox" value="d" />
<p></p>
```

JS

```
$(".generujbox").change(function () {
    var idcheck = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("p").text(idcheck);
    } else {
        $("p").text("unchecked");
    }
});
```